# Show a particular function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Suppose $k \leq d$ and $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < ... < i_k \leq d$ are integers. Show that the function $f(x_1,...,x_d)$ = $x_{i_1} x_{i_2} ... x_{i_k}$ is continuous.

I have a strong feeling that the key to this problem is the coordinate map. I have played around with this for a while but I am stuck and cannot figure out how to proceed. A simple tip or hint would suffice. Thanks.

Comment: Use curved brackets to typeset $x_{i_k}$, i.e. "x_{i_k}".

Comment: By the way, existence of derivative implies continuity.

Comment: The coordinate maps $(x_1,\ldots, x_d)\mapsto x_i$ are continuous, so $f$ is continuous as the product of continuous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove continuity at any point $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_d)$ by brute force, we have using the triangle inequality

$$|f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d)- f(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_d)| \\ = |x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\ldots x_{i_k }-a_{i_1}a_{i_2}\ldots a_{i_k }| \\ \leqslant |x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\ldots x_{i_k }-a_{i_1}x_{i_2}\ldots x_{i_k }| + |a_{i_1}x_{i_2}\ldots x_{i_k }-a_{i_1}a_{i_2}\ldots x_{i_k }|+ \\ \ldots +|a_{i_1}a_{i_2}\ldots x_{i_k }-a_{i_1}a_{i_2}\ldots a_{i_k }| \\ =|x_{i_1}-a_{i_1}||x_{i_2}|\ldots |x_{i_k}|+  |a_{i_1}||x_{i_2}-a_{i_2}|\ldots |x_{i_k}|+\\ \ldots  + |a_{i_1}||a_{i_2}|\ldots|x_{i_2}-a_{i_2}|.$$

If $\sqrt{(x_{i_1}-a_{i_1})^2 + (x_{i_2}-a_{i_2})^2 + \ldots (x_{i_k}-a_{i_k})^2} < \min(1,\delta)$ then for $p = 1, \ldots,k$ we have

$$|x_{i_p}-a_{i_p}| < \delta , \\ |x_{i_p}| < 1 + |a_{i_p}|.$$

Hence

$$|f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d)- f(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_d)| < \delta \sum_{p =1}^k \left[ \prod_{q=1}^{p-1} |a_{i_q}| \prod_{r=p+1}^k (1 + |a_{i_r}|) \right].$$

Choose

$$\delta = \epsilon \left\{ \sum_{p =1}^k\left[ \prod_{q=1}^{p-1} |a_{i_q}| \prod_{r=p+1}^k (1 + |a_{i_r}|) \right] \right\}^{-1}$$

and we have

$$|f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d)- f(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_d)| < \epsilon.$$